Binary subset rank and unrank
Let there be N=5 bits.
We want to rank and un-rank a specific subset of bits based on the following criteria -
The number of consecutive 0s must be minimum k=3 or more.

How can we rank (and unrank) only based on the given bit combination (and not by iterating the full range of 2^N bits). This will be efficient for large N bits.
Example -
N: 5 bits
k: >=3 consecutive 0s

00000 - k>=3 - rank - 00001 - unrank - 00000
00001 - k>=3 - rank - 00010 - unrank - 00001
00010 - k>=3 - rank - 00011 - unrank - 00010
00011 - k>=3 - rank - 00100 - unrank - 00011
00100
00101
00110
00111
01000 - k>=3 - rank - 00101 - unrank - 01000
01001
01010
01011
01100
01101
01110
01111
10000 - k>=3 - rank - 00110 - unrank - 10000
10001 - k>=3 - rank - 00111 - unrank - 10001
10010
10011
10100
10101
10110
10111
11000 - k>=3 - rank - 01000 - unrank - 11000
11001
11010
11011
11100
11101
11110
11111

Thanks!

Please see this article on MathSE protocol.
